# What are the composition guidelines to be followed in line art of type Mehndi designs?

Tags: drawing

[Mehndi/Henna designs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehndi) result when I search about line art in Google.
I intend to draw such designs on paper.

I could not find any [composition guidelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28visual_arts%29) regarding such designs in Google search.

Taking the following as an example what composition guidelines apply here?

[image: Easter floral henna design]

The Easter floral henna design taken from the [Can Stock Photo.](http://www.canstockphoto.com/easter-floral-henna-design-8852710.html)

Comment: It is not clear to me if you ask about making such designs on hands or on paper. I believe that your example, is computer made (might be wrong though).

Comment: @surb I am talking about paper.  I have seen artists making such designs on hand quickly. I live in India.  It is customary to have such designs on hands in marriage.

Comment: I honestly believe that these "what are the guidelines" questions are too broad. And I think your answer shows that... the answer essentially says "there are no guidelines" but here are some entire websites and links to videos that might help. Questions on SE need to be specific and answerable... this is too broad.

Comment: This question is answerable, for the attached picture. 1. The  Composition is divided into three sections by the basket and handle. the center section has larger patches of solid color, to attract the eye to the center. 2. Each leaf style is repeated several times to give coherence, but varied in size and orientation, to add interest. Same with each flower style. All lines are Smooth curves. 3. The wide expanse of the Basket gives the eye a rest, while the grid pattern adds Variety. 4. The two side sections are in balance, Joined by the basket handle.

Comment: @RobinL. Those are good observation for _this_ Mehndi, yes. That does not apply to _all_ of them though does it? Are the all baskets with leaves and floral patterns? Some of what you said it not specific to this drawing but I don't think it warrants reopening.

Answer (score 1):

I am also from India and i know about mehndi, while creating any mehndi look on hand, you need to have a Top down approach, the creation is started from the top so as to not disturb the wet mehndi you already applied to the hand and you have space at the bottom to rest your hand and create a design.

While on paper, there are no rules, it's basically doodling, you can get as creative as you want. The creativity applies to both hand and paper.Also you need to alter your designs based on where you want them, for a hand the diagram you mentioned might not work because a hands shape and size also need to be taken into account. I hope this helps because your question is a little ambiguous.

mehndi is a form of doodle art, some examples ad rules can be found at:

1. http://drawsketch.about.com/od/doodles/a/Begin-Doodling.htm
2. https://www.pinterest.com/pin/185773553351220298/
3. http://www.sparkletart.com/rsr/2013/08/doodling-for-beginners.html
4. https://www.pinterest.com/elixaa/henna-on-paper/
5. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-1ub7RR2GNY
6. http://www.lifechilli.com/draw-mehndi-designs-step-step/ (for hand, just as a refrence)

Comment: `I hope this helps because your question is a little ambiguous.` Do explain how is my question ambiguous. I will make it better.

Comment: You can  add a little more details as to what you are looking for, like you want steps to do mehndi designs or you want to create your own designs for maybe doing it on hand, or you want to copy it on paper, i know you want composition guidelines, but mehndi is a form of doodle art, you can look up those rules, I will include some links in my answer.

Comment: The "GOLDEN RATIO" is a good visual stating point.  Google it and you'll see how nature imitates art, or rather the other way around and when you look at the attached artwork again, the movement of the ratio will be visible.